# FIle Name Pickups in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssas

```
@[User::FTP_FILE] + "Test_" 
+ RIGHT((DT_STR,4,1252)YEAR(DATEADD("DD",0, (GETDATE()))),4)  +
"-"+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1254)MONTH(DATEADD("DD",0,(GETDATE()))),2) +
"-"+  RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1254)DAY(DATEADD("DD",0,(GETDATE()))),2)+
 "_"+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART( "hh", @[System::StartTime]),2)+ (DT_WSTR,1)
  "-      "+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART( "mi", @[System::StartTime]),2)+ (DT_WSTR,1)"-"
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART( "ss", @[System::StartTime]),2) +
"_transactions_report.csv"
```

But the issue was it shouldn't take start time of the container... I have the files loading at 1-41-00 to 1-45-00 EST depends on the user sends me files.. what will be the best approach to pickup this files whatever the time stamp may be using expression?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide some context? We have blob of code, what should it do. What does it do? How does it deviate from the desirable state?

Comment: Why is this tagged with SSAS? I see no Analysis Services topic here, just SSIS flat file import.

Comment: Basically it needs to pickup CSV files from server where time stamp is changing according to file loading. Since the time stamp is varying day by day i need to accomplish a task without considering the time stamp itself. The above code is always taking current time stamp when the job is running and couldn't recognize the file name. So i am looking for some dynamic code to pickup the files without considering the timestamp

Comment: Have you considered using a For Each File iterator, of which you will find a zillion examples online.

Comment: and this is why I make no effort in answering these... the OP just disappears.....

Comment: @ElectricLlama Thanks for your help. sorry if you get offended for not getting reply from me. I am travelling whole day yesterday

Comment: I didn't mean to be grumpy. Would you be so kind as to give us an example of the files that appear in the folder? Then go through the tutorial on this page: http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx and let us know when you get stuck.

Comment: There will be 15 files that i am receiving from a vendor all needs to be loaded into different tables. But vendor sends me the the files with the time stamps of when he ran. For an example he ran the file at 1:00:00 EST i will get the file by 2:00:00 EST but the file name will be still 1:00:00 EST. SO when i have to run the package either it is taking system start time or container start time.. which cant be correct since file name has 1:00:00 EST but SSIS is searching for 2:00:00 EST

Comment: With my understanding from FOR EACH LOOP. I couldn't use for Each loop since all the fifteen files are loading into the same folder so when i have to differentiate each file and have to load into appropriate table using SSIS. I may be wrong here

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Getdate() instead of @[System::StartTime. You can pick the files using Foreach Container where you can choose the file extension by assigning folder name.

Comment: Thanks. I will have fifteen different CSV is the same folder which is loading on daily basis which needs to load into 15 different tables. As i am new to SSIS I am thinking for each loop container will pickup all the files in folder. I may be wrong here

Comment: The best approach for your case is as follows: 1) you can create a variable that is dynamic according to the table name. 2) you can do ForEach loop container and add a DFT inside that does take a file and dump into the table and loop.